# Electric field at an axial location of a semicircular ring of non-uniform charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, integration

Suppose there is a semi-circle of radius R and center O contains a non-uniform charge distribution on its perimeter. Let P be a general point at an angular position $\theta$ ( $\theta$ measured relative to radius OA). If $$ \lambda_{P} = \lambda_{0}(1+\sin\theta)$$where $\lambda_0$ is a positive constant,

Find electric field's magnitude at an axial location which is at a distance $z$ from O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with small element $dl$ on circle this $dl$ is at angle of $\theta$ from OA

Since R is constant $dl = Rd \theta$

The magnitude of Electric Field due to this on axis at distance of $z$
$$dE = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\frac{dq}{r^2}$$

$r$ = distance of point from charge $dq$

$$dq = \lambda_P\times dl = \lambda_0(1+sin\ \theta)Rd\theta$$

$$r^2 = R^2+z^2$$
$$dE = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\lambda_0(1+sin\ \theta)Rd\theta}{R^2+z^2}$$

Now you can integrate this from $0$ to $\pi$
$$E = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\lambda_0R}{R^2+z^2}\int_0^\pi(1+sin\ \theta)d\theta$$

$$E= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\lambda_0R(\pi+2)}{R^2+z^2}$$